# file_get_contents("php://input") showing null when var_dump

Tags: php, json

`file_get_contents("php://input");` is not working.

`$data=$_GET['json'];` is working.

my url:

> http://localhost/demo/plainjson.php?json={"order_number":"54321","id":"1102","status":3,"card_no":"1234"}

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($json);// o/p->Null
print_r($json);// o/p-> nothing

echo $json[2];
```

how to echo or print the url json array or value using this need help.
with explanation.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Please ignore last code line echo $json[2]; it's also echo false or nothing i don't know.

Comment: In the request you put the json in a querystring var called `json`, therefor, shouldn't the json_decode be on `$data['json']` rather than just `$data`?

Comment: i am not happy man, for this i have to learn Cake PHP now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`allow_url_include` may not be set to true in your php.ini? This is common on some older shared hosting services

Refer to this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794604/file-get-contents-not-working) post for a potential fix.

Ahhh... The problem is that you arent POSTing anything. But rather sending it via query string so there is no body for the stream to retrieve. So as I understand it you cannot use a streams to get the data

[See PHP.net Aritical](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

"php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. In the case of POST request"

Further more see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692712/php-input-contains-data-for-a-get-request)

Comment: checked i changed the value from: allow_url_include = off to on in php.ini and restarted the wamp. m using wamp. still not working.

Comment: so, can you tell m hw to post data? on the same page where i want use file_get_contents("php://input") function to get values. i knw smwht stupid but.. :)

Comment: Well there are a couple of options. You can submit a form with your data in a form field and the form method type to POST. Or you can do it in PHP via cURL. Refer to - http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post - for more instructions on that.

Comment: if your site is https and we submit a POST request of content type JSON using a http url of the site, then you may get php://input as null.when submitting data to a https website using https could be better