# php://input is empty on server but it work on localhost

Tags: php, apache, http

I am trying to make a PUT request with the following, and it works just fine on localhost but it show empty once I try to run it on my domain. I have checked that PHP versions are the same on both localhost and shared server. I checked the and made sure that `allow_url_fopen=On`. Basically this is the part that does not work. I am trying to get the body of the PUT request from the 'php://input' with the following `parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $_PUT);` and it returns empty. Moreover when I check to see if the file exists `file_exists('php://input')`, it says the file does not exists.

I read that these are called wrappers. I have tried reading from different variables and files but it still does not work.

/**************** EDIT ***************/

```
var ajax = function(object){
    var oo, xhr;
    oo = j2.extend({
        method: 'get',
        credentials: false,
        beforesend: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }, object);


    if("XMLHttpRequest" in window){
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e){
        if(xhr.readyState === 4){
            oo.complete && oo.complete(xhr);

            if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300){
                oo.success && oo.success(xhr);  
            }
            else if(xhr.status >= 400 && xhr.status < 600){
                oo.error && oo.error(xhr);
            }   
        }
        else if((xhr.readyState === 3) && (oo.loading)){
            oo.loading(xhr);
        }
        else if((xhr.readyState === 2) && (oo.headers)){
            oo.headers(xhr)
        }
        else if((xhr.readyState === 1) && (oo.received)){
            oo.received(xhr);
        }
    }

    xhr.open(oo.method, oo.action, true);
    xhr.withCredentials = oo.credentials;

    j2.foreach(oo.beforesend, function(v, k){
        xhr.setRequestHeader(k, v);
    });

    xhr.send(oo.data);
};


ajax({ method: 'put', action: 'the url to send the request'
    , data: _.data(form) /* function that url encodes the inputs in the form*/
    , received: function(){
        form.update.disabled = true;
    }
    , success: function(xhr){
        _.process(xhr);
    }
    , error: function(xhr){
        _.process(xhr);
    }
    , complete: function(){
        form.update.disabled = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling PHP error reporting?

Comment: I think I have. But could you please tell me how to verify!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Yes, I have then! Nothings shows!

Comment: What does `echo file_get_contents('php://input') ` give you? Maybe the string is just not parseable as you expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents("php://input") showing null when var\_dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175002/file-get-contentsphp-input-showing-null-when-var-dump)

Comment: @jaswrks file_get_contents('php://input') echoes null. so I don't believe is a parsing problem

Comment: @dsadnick it is not a duplicate 1) I am actually making a post. 2) Allow url_encode_include is set 3) It works on localhost

Comment: What does $args = array(); parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $args); var_dump( $args ); output?

Comment: @JesseSchokker it outputs array(0) {}

Comment: How does your PUT request look? Are you sure it's not being blocked by CORS?

Comment: Are you running any other PHP framework or library that might be reading `file_get_contents('php://input')` before you do? I believe it can only be read once.

Comment: @JesseSchokker I don't believe it is blocked by CORS as it does not show any message regading a problem with that. I have edited my answer so you can see my ajax requets

Comment: I am also facing same issue, JSON post works on localhost and does not work on server (cpanel). Any suggestions?