# Getting header info through php://input

Tags: php, laravel, header

I am trying to get my webhooks header (Woocommerce webhook),

I am retrieving the body with file_get_contents('php://input'), although this only gives the body according to http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

I also found this thread: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175002/file-get-contentsphp-input-showing-null-when-var-dump), but I can't figure it out.
Is there any other function that gives me back the header?

My function looks like this:

```
public function webhook(Request $request) {
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', $json);
}
```

---

Edit: Other things I tried:

```
public function webhook(Request $request) {
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $headers = getallheaders();
    Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', $headers['Content-Name']);
}
```

This sets the webhook to "Disabled", I suppose this throws an error for some reason.

`apache_request_headers` is not changing the status to "Disabled" but is returning an empty file.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ones who might be facing the same problem in the future, I found the following solution:

```
public function webhook(Request $request) {
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', $json);
    Storage::disk('local')->put('request.txt', Request::header('x-wc-webhook-source'));
}
```

Main url solution: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186389/how-do-i-receive-the-webhooks-payload)

Answer (score 1):

### Use [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php):

This function exists for the sole purpose of retrieving request headers:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
var_dump($headers['Content-Name']);
```

Comment: Thank you, but already tried this.
It seems that the codes returns an error because it sets the webhook to disabled after updating the code with it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other function that gives me back the header?

Assuming you use Apache, then: http://php.net/apache-request-headers

Comment: Returning an empty file.txt, I suppose it is not retrieving any header.